# Passing JSON URL to java Restful WebService

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a JSON url,i want to Parse the URL and get the information from the URL
My requirement is to write a java restfull web service which accepts JSON URL as input and which returns the data
I have followed the tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/ he passed a String to the WebService method

Could any one help to Write a  java WebService?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build your own RESTful API and want to parse that data then use [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)
and If you have API present and want to parse data then use this [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)